# Insert script with select clause not working

Tags: sql

I have insert script

```
Insert into tblsc_zone (ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,sup,country)(
select SEQ.NEXTVAL,'vrt',NULL, ag,cid from (
select distinct STG_VIEW.aggg AS AG ,STG_VIEW.coun AS CID 
FROM dummy STG_VIEW)
);
```

it is not working showing invalid number of columns.

But I have correctly defined all the column names and in proper sequence also

```
select SEQ.NEXTVAL,'vrt',NULL, ag,cid from (
select distinct STG_VIEW.aggg AS AG ,STG_VIEW.coun AS CID 
FROM dummy STG_VIEW)
```

also if I am executing without this inner query

```
select distinct STG_VIEW.aggg AS AG ,STG_VIEW.coun AS CID 
FROM dummy STG_VIEW
```

it is working fine.

But it is inserting duplicate records.

So it fetch unique combination of agg and country I am using this subquery.

Please guide me how to make it work

I want to insert the unique combination of agg and country in this table.

Comment: it will help to have: 1. name of rdbms vendor. 2. error message.

Comment: also consider using sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1):

Remove the braces before select in insert statement and try

```
Insert into tblsc_zone (ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,sup,country)
select SEQ.NEXTVAL,'vrt',NULL, ag,cid from (
select distinct STG_VIEW.aggg AS AG ,STG_VIEW.coun AS CID 
FROM dummy STG_VIEW)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler:

```
Insert into tblsc_zone (ID,NAME,sup,country)
select DISTINCT SEQ.NEXTVAL,'vrt', aggg ,coun 
FROM dummy STG_VIEW
```

There could be a problem with `DISTINCT` and `NULL` as `NULL != NULL` in SQL